# Unable to avoid job triggering at Start up

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spring-batch, batch-processing, job-scheduling, spring-scheduled

I am using a batch process and i want it to run at a specific cron scheduled time. However, the job is getting triggered at the start up and again triggering at the scheduled time. I am trying to avoid the former however failing to do so. This is a sample repository which reproduces the same issue: https://github.com/ppanigrahi02/BatchJobWithScheduler. i am using the spring guide example https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing and added a scheduler on top of it. I will really appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Scheduled` annotation used [here](https://github.com/ppanigrahi02/BatchJobWithScheduler/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/JobScheduler.java#L24) will start the job immediately at startup and every 600000 milliseconds. If you want to specify an initial delay to wait before the first execution, you can use the `initialDelay` attribute of the annotation, something like:

`@Scheduled(initialDelay = 600000, fixedRate = 600000)`

Another option is to use the `cron` attribute and provide a cron expression. For more details about this annotation, you can check the reference documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected with `@Scheduled(cron = "0 32 18 1/1 * ?")
`